# Symmetric difference of two minimal edge cuts is a cut.

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that when we have two minimal edge cuts (such that if any edge from the cut is put back in the graph it's connected again), it's symmetric difference is too a cut (not exactly minimal).

How to do this?

I just don't see it. If we erase the symmetric difference of two edge cuts there's still a distinct possibility (for me at least), that we still have a connected graph thanks to the edges they have in common.

We probably have to use the fact that these two are minimal cuts, but once again, I have no idea how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the two (minimal) cuts $C_1 = (U,U')$ and $C_2 = (W,W')$. Then their symmetric difference contains all the edges in the cut $C_3 = (Z,Z')$ where $Z = (W\cap U)\cup(W'\cap U')$, and $Z' = V\setminus Z = (W\cap U')\cup(W'\cap U)$. To see why, assume it is not, i.e., WLOG, the symmetric difference cut leaves an edge connecting $W\cap U$ to $W\cap U'$. This edge is in $C_1$ and not in $C_2$, so it must be included in the symmetric difference - which contradicts the initial assumption.